# Why is the result value of the compare operation different from the mathematically same formula?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm having trouble comparing size of a vector and simple constant `-1`

I believe both of these are logically the same:

- `(index >= (arr.size() - 1))`
- `((index + 1) >= arr.size())`

However, the first one returns `1` not `0`.
What's the difference between the two comparisons?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int index = -1;
  vector<char> arr(6);
  cout << (index >= (arr.size() - 1)) << endl;
  cout << ((index + 1) >= arr.size()) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @n.m.  Unfortunately, arr.size()-1 just returns 5.
`cout << arr.size() - 1 << endl;`

Comment: pay attention to warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/xMrz4nT6a. And note that in C++20 there is `std::ssize` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `arr.size` method returns an unsigned integer type, so the type of the right-hand side of the comparison is unsigned.  This results in the left side being converted to unsigned.

When the value on the left is -1, this gets converted to a very large unsigned number, resulting in the first comparison being true.  In the second case, the value on the left is 0 so it doesn't change when being converted to an unsigned type and the comparison is false.

If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` it will warn you about a signed / unsigned comparison.

Comment: Narrowing integer conversations result in compilation warnings. I wish this answer had mentioned it.

Answer (score 4):

**size_t** is an unsigned long long.
**int** is a signed type.
You are trying to compare an unsigned type with a signed one. The size of the vector will never have the value -1.

Comment: `size_t` is *some* unsigned type (but not necessarily `unsigned long long` specifically).

Comment: Also, `vector<char>::size_type` is not necessarily the same as `std::size_t`. And neither is necessarily the same as `unsigned long long`. What is necessarily the case is that all these types are unsigned.